# Adding Double and a String to then display on a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to add up a value that is entered in the text field with a value specified as a double and then returning the value on a label. The code that I have is :

```
@IBOutlet weak var enterField: UITextField!

var weekOneTotal:Double = 0

 @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
        addCorrectValue()

    }

func addCorrectValue () {
        guard let addAmount = convertAmount(input: enterField.text!) else {
            print("Invalid amount")
            return
        }

      let newValue = weekOneTotal += addAmount

        secondScreen.weekOneAmountLabel.text = String(newValue)

}

  func convertAmount (input:String) -> Double? {

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter ()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

        return numberFormatter.number(from: input)?.doubleValue
    }
```

Comment: BTW - Please [edit] your question and clearly state what issues you are having with the code you posted. Show exact and complete error messages. Point out the exact lines causing the errors or problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to increase value of `weekOneTotal` variable by converted amount and then you want to use this value as `text` of some label

```
weekOneTotal += addAmount
secondScreen.weekOneAmountLabel.text = String(weekOneTotal)
```

Comment: @AlexBrook Btw, its not what you’re trying to do, see the differences. With my code you dont have to create new constant, but you just increase weakOneTotal

Comment: no, getting an error message for the label line "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @AlexBrook this error isnt connected with number logic but with instance of label that isnt the same instance as label connected with outlet from storyboard

Comment: @AlexBrook look to comment above, How is this label related with your controller?

Comment: Thanks, I am using the label that has been connected with outlet from storyboard. is there something in particular I need to check?

Comment: class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
  //outlets
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var weekOneAmountLabel: UILabel!

Comment: @AlexBrook its not the same instance of controller so outlet isnt connected and label is then nil. So you need to pass data between controllers using delegate pattern or callback closure, find some answers to this topic on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func addCorrectValue () {
    guard let addAmount = Double(enterField.text!) else {
        print("Invalid amount")
        return
    }

    let newValue = weekOneTotal + addAmount

    secondScreen.weekOneAmountLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.1f", newValue))"
}
```

The .1 is the number of decimals that are shown. You can adjust that to your needs. Hope I understood the question and this works for you!

Comment: That also means you can get rid of `convertAmount`

Comment: The OP wants to keep `convertAmount` because it properly handles numbers entered in the user's locale. This code will fail if the user enters a decimal value such as `3,14`. A number formatter should also be used to format the new total when updating the label so the number is formatter for the user's locale.

Comment: hi, thanks, I am getting an error message 

"Constant 'newValue' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected "

for the line 

"let newValue = weekOneTotal += addAmount"

Comment: I added the amendments you suggested but still getting this error for label line "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @AlexBrook Which one is the "label line"? This one: `secondScreen.weekOneAmountLabel.text ...`? Did you check that the secondScreen and the weekOneAmountLabel is not nil?

Comment: @AlexBrook The error about the unexpected type is because of the additional "=" you have in that line. Please change to: `let newValue = weekOneTotal + addAmount`

Comment: @ Robin Bork thanks! managed to get it working, I didn't have the view controllers connected correctly as @Robert Dresler mentioned in the comments below :)